# Fourier Transform of 2D data using Fourier

Tags: numerics, fourier-analysis

I don't understand the [documentation of `Fourier`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fourier.html). My goal is the get the coefficients of the Fourier-series (i.e. $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} c_{n,m} e^{inx+imy}$) of data points which looks like this: `{{datapoint1,{x,y}},...}`

However, according to its docs `Fourier` only seems to handle lists of data points without any coordinates attached to them, pretending they are one unity apart. Although the "Details and Options" section of the documentation does say that it can parse nested lists to account for data in any dimensions, unfortunately no example is given to e.g. interpret the output.

Is there no built in function to get the coefficients of this series? This should be done **numerically**, unless the analytical approach works for arbitrary data sets. I do **not** have a workable expression for the generator of these points, `NFourierTransform` does not work.

Should I use some fitting functions instead? If so, which one is best for Fourier transforms?

Comment: `Fourier` works on regularly/uniformly sampled data. Are your `{x,y}` coordinates uniform and are they sorted properly? If so you could just do `Fourier[data[[All, All, 1]]]`. If not, you'll need to sample it first.

Comment: @flinty I can sample them uniformly, such that essentially the x-y Plane becomes a grid. But how does `Fourier` even know it should return to me the coefficients of a 2D fourier series? The way you write it, I again just get a list of datapoints, but I have lost all information on where they once where? I edited my question to account for another comment in the docs.

Comment: Yes but that's expected. When you move to the frequency domain you lose all that time/space information. If you want to preserve it, I'm afraid that's impossible, though if you use wavelets you can preserve *some* of the time/space information. [See here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-does-the-uncertainty-principle-limit-time-series-analysis-c94c442ba953)

Comment: @flinty Perhaps I have not really explained what I want. I do not want to preserve the information of their coordinates, but the fact that they lived in 2D. That is, the fourier transform of these data should also give me coefficients of a basis in "2D frequency space" (i.e. two different frequencies per basis element.)

Comment: You are mixing up Fourier _Series_ and the Fourier _Transform_. When you run `Fourier` on an array of numbers, it will output an array of the same dimension but full of complex numbers. It also says in the docs that `Fourier` is equivalent to multiplication with a `FourierMatrix`. If you go to the docs for `FourierMatrix` you'll see the layout.

Comment: @flinty Ohhhh, I see. Alright, thanks! This makes more sense now

Comment: Maybe experimenting a bit will help you: `With[{f = 7, n = 50}, data = Table[Cos[2 \[Pi]  (f  x)/n], {x, n}, {y, n}]; MatrixPlot[Abs[Fourier[data]], ColorFunction -> GrayLevel]]` Here I have set up a cos wave with frequency f=7 (relative to the sample rate of 50). If you look at the brightest pixel, you'll see it appears on row 7+1 because row 1 col 1 is the DC coefficient 0 Hz. There is also the symmetric part at row 50-7+1 (because this is a Real valued signal). If we do the same but change x to y, we get a vertical cos wave, and you get the same thing but with the columns instead of rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the 1D case, the FFT is a linear transformation. Therefore it can be done multiplying the data vector by a matrix. Here is an example:

```
n=5;
dat=RandomReal[{-1,1},n];
fmat=FourierMatrix[n];
Fourier[dat] == fmat.dat

True
```

For the 2D case you  FFT the rows, then the columns separately. This can be written in MMA rather compact. Here is an example, remembering that the Fourier matrix is symmetrical:

```
n = 5;
fmat = FourierMatrix[n];
d = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
Fourier[d] == fmat . d . fmat

True
```

For the 3D case, we first write the general formula using sums:

```
n = 3;
fm = FourierMatrix[n];
dat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n, n}];
Table[Sum[
   fm[[j1, i1]]   fm[[j2, i2]] fm[[j3, i3]] dat[[i1, i2, i3]], {i1, 
    n}, {i2, n}, {i3, n}], {j1, n}, {j2, n}, {j3, n}] == Fourier[dat]

True
```

This can easily be extended to higher dimensions. But we may write the same  more compact using Dot, what is a bit more complicated because of the needed Transpositions (with more complicated calculations, we get small numerical errors due to machine precision):

```
n = 3;
fm = FourierMatrix[n];
dat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n, n}];
Table[Sum[
   fm[[j1, i1]]   fm[[j2, i2]] fm[[j3, i3]] dat[[i1, i2, i3]], {i1, 
    n}, {i2, n}, {i3, n}], {j1, n}, {j2, n}, {j3, n}] - Fourier[dat] //Chop

{{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
   0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}
```

Comment: Good exposition to also clarify what is meant in the docs about nested lists. Thanks!